# is there a way to get the final object space normal (with normal maps applied)

Tags: node-editor, normals, normal-map

Im trying to create a light source within a shader, this light source needs to be in object space.

I have created a node network that does this well, but only uses the mesh normals (in object space), i thought adding the normal map would be simple but im struggling to get something that works correctly and have with help over engineered several solutions including recreating a TBN matrix (think this didn't work as the tangents didn't appear as i would expect them)

however im thinking there must be a simpler solution that im missing? get pixels normal (mesh + map), transform to local space, do stuff?...

Answer (score 0):

its very simple, the normalmap output in tangent mode does exactly what i was looking for, i was being dumb, i had refactored my node networks into a bunch of nested groups and one of the inputs had set the normal intput to a float instead of a vector...

it took me to recreate the entire normal tbn matrix in nodes and debug the out put vs the normalmap node to realise ;)